# Are static member functions in c++ copied in multiple translation units?

Tags: c++, static-members

I have a helper class in my program which has many static functions used in different classes of my program. E.g.

`helper.h`:

```
Class helper {
 public: 
   static void fn1 () 
   { /* defined in header itself */ }

   /* fn2 defined in src file helper.cpp */
   static void fn2(); 
}
```

Helper has only static member functions. So, no objects of helper are created by other modules. Helper functions are used in other modules like:

`A.cpp`

```
#include "helper.h"
A::foo() {
  helper::fn1(); 
  helper::fn2();
}
```

`B.cpp`

```
#include "helper.h"
B::foo() {
  helper::fn1();
  helper::fn2(); 
}
```

Does the compiler create separate copies of helper functions in `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`? I read some earlier posts and I gathered from the replies that compiler will create so. But when I print the address of `fn1` and `fn2` as `printf("Address of fn1 is %p\n", &helper::fn1);` and `printf("Address of fn1 is %p\n", &helper::fn1);` from both `A.cpp` and `B.cpp`, I get the same address. I'm confused now. Can someone clarify, If I'm missing something.

The reason I'm worried about multiple copies of helper functions (if it happens) is we are trying to reduce our executable size and wanted to optimize it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Functions defined inside the class body are implicitly marked `inline`.  If you take the address of the function, the compiler will also create a regular copy of the function (per compilation unit), but the linker will pick just one of these copies to include in the executable, so there's only one address.

However, the inlining process could make many copies of the function, even more than the number of compilation units.  Often the increased size of duplicating the code is offset by the increased optimization possible by eliminating argument passing and function call overhead, as well as opportunities for common subexpression elimination, etc.  Although inlining is often considered a tradeoff between size and speed, the size increase is often negligible or even negative.

The function that's just declared in the class and then implemented in a single compilation unit, definitely has just one copy in the executable.

Comment: +1. I should have read the question a little more carefully ;) Deleted my post.

Comment: @snkrish: Is that a template static member function or a template static global function?  If it's a static member function, you'll probably get a new copy for each combination of template parameters, but the number of compilation units still won't affect it.  If a static global (or namespace) function, you will get a new copy in each compilation unit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, now I see why the address was same. I have a follow up question, I'm not sure if I should start a separate post. If the same fn2 above was written using templates as: template <typnename T> static void fn2() ; - should fn2 be defined in header itself or should I use extern template <typename T> helper::fn2() { /* definition in helper.cpp */ } to optimize executable size. Will compiler create one copy of the function, whenever fn2 is called with a different T, irrespective of how it is defined?

Comment: Templates really need to go in the header.  If you put them into just a single compilation unit, the compiler won't know what values of `T` to specialize the template with, and then you'll get linker errors.  The compiler will generate a `fn2<T>` for each different `T`, and it doesn't matter how many compilation units cause the compiler to do that, because the linker will keep only one (for each `T`).

Comment: Isn't this a bad design? I think that it's better to use namespaces to group those functions.

Comment: There's not enough information to determine that. In any case, the question is about member functions.

Answer (score 2):

if visible (e.g., defined in the class declaration), then it's implicitly declared inline by many compilers.

if inlined, then yes it may be copied in some cases, inlined in some cases, and partially inlined in other cases.

it follows the One Definition Rule (ODR), copies found in multiple translations will be removed when linked (unless you have enabled private extern inlines, then you could really end up with redundant exported implementations).

if you are coming from C: static does not create a unique copy of the function in this case -- it just means that you may call the function without an instance of the class which declares it.

Comment: Thanks I'm using static to just call fn1 and fn2 without creating a helper object.

Comment: @srikrish i see that. i only mentioned it because C programmers are accustomed to functions declared as static to affect linkage (which would produce private copies when not inlined in every known use -- relevant to the question). it is a common source of confusion for them. because of that, and since i don't know your background... i added that last detail.

Answer (score 0):

An inlined static class method is not that different from an inlined free function. Theoretically the ODR rule means that there is a single instance of the function, but in practice the compiler may have always inlined it so that there is in fact no instance of the function per se.

However, the very act of ***taking the address*** of the function will force the compiler to create an instance of the function, and it is the compilation system's problem to enforce the ODR and hence ensure that you always get the same address.